# What is better than Mechanize in Python?

Tags: python, mechanize

I want to submit a form, follow link, select some check boxes & Radio buttons and click on buttons through my Python Program. I have worked with Perl's Mechanize. I checked google and I found its available for Python too

```
http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/
```

Unfortunately, that link is dead! So, where can I get some Python Mechanize's tutorials and where can I download it from? If not mechanize, what else would you suggest?

Comment: That's just SF being stupid. It'll come back up eventually.

Comment: that link is working for me now

Comment: you can try [ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this link:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize

If not mechanize then webdriver driving webkit or webunit backend from Python is an option. Or just use the webkit bindings from Python directly.

Answer (score 4):

Also, where mechanize fails try using [splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/).

Answer (score 1):

Keith already pointed you to the correct mechanize link. Apart from that, you can try [selenium bindings](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) ([tutorial](https://gist.github.com/1047207))available for python too.